# Validation message, using :base and validates_associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a problem to display an error message.

I have a class that has another class.

This way:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :attachments, class_name: 'IssueAttachment', dependent: :destroy, autosave:   true
 validates_associated :attachments, :message => [:base] << "-- Teste --"
```

and

```
class IssueAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :issue, counter_cache: :attachments_count
  validate :suspitious_attachment

  private
    def suspitious_attachment
      if ends_with? '.bat', '.com', '.exe', '.src', '.cmd'
        errors.add(:base, "..teste..")
      end
    end

  def ends_with?(*args)
    args.each do |arg|
      return true if attachment.path.ends_with? arg
    end
    false
  end
```

In the error message I want to display the following:
...test ...

But now the message that appears is:
Attachments base ...teste...
Attachments -- Teste --

The first error message refers to line:
validates_associated :attachments, :message = > [:base ] << "--Teste--"

And the second:
errors.add ( :base , "...teste..." )

In both cases I'm displaying the attribute , and I do not want this , I want to display only the message.
The command : base simply does not work , I've tried all variations and the message does not change.

What am I doing wrong?
Can anyone help me?

Sorry for the english :P

Comment: how are you displaying the error messages?

Comment: The messages are in a translation file.

But anyway I am displaying the messages within the method and in front of validates_associated.                                     Here: errors.add(:base, "..teste..")
and here

validates_associated :attachments, :message => [:base] << "-- Teste --"